# How do I create a Web Service in IronPython?

Tags: .net, web-services, ironpython

How do I create a .Net Web Service in IronPython?
Preferably dynamically without any pre- or post-processing.

Comment: What do you mean without pre/post processing?

Comment: I think he means without manual compilation to an assembly.

Comment: Exactly, without any extra build steps.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the sample called DynamicWebServiceHelpers in the recently released [IronPython 2.0](http://www.codeplex.com/IronPython/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=8365).

Comment: That sample is about calling a web service. I'm interested in creating the the service on the server side.

Comment: The sample doesn't work on linux - DynamicWebServiceHelpers.dll isn't included

Comment: This project is intended for the *consumption* of web services, not the creation of them. From the documentation: "The Dynamic Web Service Helpers library is intended to simplify the consumption of web services for IronPython developers. This package includes the DynamicWebServiceHelpers 
sources and a set of samples that show how to utilize them."

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this, but it's something I've tried to look for in the past.

Maybe Look at the following :

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywebsvcs/